# What specifically was the ancient Jewish practice of rubbing an infant's throat?

Tags: history, children-parenting, science, drinking

The [Jewish Encyclopedia article on "Consecration"](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4612-consecration) says that the later "rubbing on" of oil aka "anointing" has roots in the practice of rubbing an infant's throat in preparation for receiving a mother's milk:

> CONSECRATION or DEDICATION:
>
> By: Emil G. Hirsch, Kaufmann Kohler
>
> The solemn setting apart of a person or thing to a special use or purpose. According to Fleischer (Levy, "Neuhebr. Wörterb." ii. 206), the word "ḥanak" (to initiate) is derived from the "rubbing of the throat" of an infant for the purpose of cleansing it and enabling it to take the mother's milk, and is therefore applied to every form of initiation. It appears, moreover, that the "rubbing" remained for a long time an essential feature of the rite of initiation, for "every consecration in Biblical times was accompanied by rubbing or anointing with oil the object to be consecrated. Thus the pillar at Bethel was anointed (Gen. xxviii. 18; compare the "dedication" of Nebuchadnezzar's image, Dan. iii. 2 et seq.). The priests and the vessels of the Tabernacle were anointed with oil (Ex. xxviii. 41, xxx. 26; Lev. viii. 10-12; Num. vii. 13), and by this rite they were "hallowed." "Mishḥat Adonai" is, therefore, "consecration to the Lord" (Lev. x. 7)...

I find this a promising line of inquiry into the otherwise mysterious practice of anointing but, perhaps because I'm not a mother, nothing I can relate to or picture. Can someone please explain the practice in terms I might understand?

One thing I would like clarified is whether this rubbing of the baby's throat was done by the mother each time she breastfed or whether it was done by a priest to bless the child's ability to feed throughout life.

Comment: MISHNA IN SHABBAT החושש במתניו לא יסוך יין וחומץ אבל סך הוא את השמן ולא שמן וורד בני מלכים סכין שמן ורד על מכותיהן שכן דרכן לסוך בחול ר"ש אומר כל ישראל בני מלכים הם ?May be linked

Comment: @kouty Can you improve on the https://translate.google.com translation?:  "The fear of his gift will not lubricate wine and vinegar, but the oil is neither oil nor rose kings oil knife and a rose knife on their bumps as their path to lubricate in the sand says all Israel kings are"

Comment: @Ruminator “someone who has pain in their waist should not rub/smear wine or vinegar (on his shoulders) but they may rub oil. But not rose oil. Royalty may rub rose oil on their wounds because that is their norm, to rub rose oil also in a weekday. Rabbi Shimon says all children of israel are royalty.” Translation is mine but I think is correct.

Comment: @mroll  Thanks. It doesn't appear to me, then, to be relevant to consecration.